# bash edit-and-execute-command shortcut under screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

How can I reconfigure `screen`'s keybinding `C-x` (lock the screen, useless for me) so it doesn't mask bash's `edit-and-execute-command` bound to `C-x C-e`?

Comment: You can do: `C-a C-x C-e`

Comment: 1. `C-a C-x C-e` doesn't work -- screen locks. AFAIK you can't unbind just `C-a C-x`. you can only do `unbindall`. 2. I'd prefer to not think about "am I under screen at the moment or am I not?", so the question is just about very specific combo: `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Sorry, it's bee a while since I used screen. I think it's actually `C-a a C-x C-e`. The `C-a a` should prevent the following from being read by screen.

Comment: I ended up remapping prefix sequence for screen from `C-a` to `C-b` (with `echo "escape ^Bb" >> ~/.screenrc`) and now I can use `C-x C-e`.